# when i am clicking on button then tyface.default.getstyle() is not working

Tags: android

My problem is that when i click on button then my text should be bold from there, and if i press that button again then text should be unbold from there. i am using this given code , by the help of this code when i click on button then then text is bold from there, but when i press button again then text is not unbold from there....

```
boldButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                if(boldBoolean==false)
                {
                    startTemp = edtTouch.getSelectionStart();
                    endTemp = edtTouch.getSelectionStart();
                    temp=edtTouch.getText().toString();
                    Spannable span=edtTouch.getText();
                    StyleSpan boldText=new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
                    span.setSpan(boldText, startTemp, startTemp, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    span.setSpan(boldText, startTemp, startTemp, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    boldButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bold_bracket);
                    boldBoolean=true;

                }
                else
                {

                /*  Spannable span=edtTouch.getText();
                    StyleSpan boldText=new StyleSpan(Typeface.DEFAULT.getStyle());
                    span.setSpan(boldText, startTemp, startTemp,     Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    boldButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bold);
                    boldBoolean=false;*/


                }

            }
        });
```

if anyone know about it then please help me...

Thank in Advance...

Comment: Please describe the problem more carefully: what is happening and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I dont want to down vote and decrease ur points which wont allow you to post questions, Before asking questions please describe your header properly and meaningfull, no one would understand anything by just reading ur code without any background knowledge hence describe your question properly and as @OliverW. said what is expected and what is happening

Comment: thank for your reply, in this code my if condition is working great but else condition is not working. when i click first time on button then text is bold from there but when i click again that button then text is not unbold. for unbold i used Tyface.Default.getStyle(), but that is not working. and i am very stuck in this , please help me sir...

Comment: Actually implementing the `else` branch may help.

Comment: Please recheck my answered code.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
finally i got solution myself by using droidwriter.jar , you can download it from http://code.google.com/p/droid-writer/downloads/detail?name=droidwriter-0.8.jar&can=2&q=
after that i am sharing my code here
XML file:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >


    <ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bold"
         android:textOff="B"
                android:textOn="B"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     />

     <ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/italic"
         android:textOff="I"
                android:textOn="I"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <hu.scythe.droidwriter.DroidWriterEditText
            android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapSentences"
            android:minLines="10" />


</LinearLayout>
```

/*   And my java code  */

```
package com.example.editordemo;

import hu.scythe.droidwriter.DroidWriterEditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ToggleButton bold,italic;
    DroidWriterEditText edt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        bold=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bold);
        italic=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.italic);
        edt=(DroidWriterEditText) findViewById(R.id.DwEdit);
        edt.setBoldToggleButton(bold);
        edt.setItalicsToggleButton(italic);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I have done your solution, Please try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    short clickedTime=0;
    TextView tv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }


    private void akash()
    {
        if(clickedTime==0)
        {
        SpannableString text = new SpannableString(tv.getText().toString());

        text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd(),0);

        tv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        clickedTime=1;

        }
        else
        {
            SpannableString text = new SpannableString(tv.getText().toString());

            text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL),tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd(),0);

            tv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            clickedTime=0;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        akash();
    }

}
```

Comment: I found the solution and edited the code please check this one.

Comment: @ Akash i want to do something like this application on google play store, please check the functionality of bold button of this app, link of app is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spn.richnotepad&hl=en